# Embedded answers in math mode (cloze, moodle)

Tags: moodle, r-exams

I want create questions with [R-exams](http://r-exams.org/) to Moodle. In my case I want use `cloze` type and embed answers into math mode:

```
<<echo=FALSE,hide=TRUE>>=
@
\exname{foo}
\exsection{bar}
\extype{cloze}
\exclozetype{num|num}
\exsolution{1|1}
\begin{question}
  What are the answers?
  \[x_1=\frac{##ANSWER1##}{##ANSWER2##}\]
\end{question}
```

I can build Moodle-compatible XML but when I import it into Moodle it goes wrong:
[image: bad result]

I tried `\text{##ANSWER1##}` but same result. I think the MathJax wants parse it too.

How can I use `##ANSWERx##` in math mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find a solution that works inside LaTeX math when rendered by MathJax. My impression is that when the numerical fill-in-the-blank fields are inserted to the mathematical formula, the MathJax rendering does not work.

I see two possible workarounds: (1) Use a {table} with math markup for certain elements. (2) Use MathML rather than MathJax (i.e., works in Firefox and Safari but not Chrome).

#### 1. Use a {table} instead.

```
\begin{question}
What are the answers?

\begin{tabular}{rc}
        & ##ANSWER1##                        \\
$x_1 =$ & \rule{\linewidth}{2\linethickness} \\
        & ##ANSWER2##
\end{tabular}
\end{question}

\exname{frac}
\extype{cloze}
\exclozetype{num|num}
\exsolution{1|1}
```

If you store the exercise code above in a file called `frac.Rnw` then using

```
exams2moodle("frac.Rnw")
```

and importing it into Moodle yields:

[image: frac table]

#### 2. Use MathML

```
\begin{question}
What are the answers?

\[ x_1 = \frac{\text{##ANSWER1##}}{\text{##ANSWER2##}} \]
\end{question}

\exname{frac}
\extype{cloze}
\exclozetype{num|num}
\exsolution{1|1}
```

If you store this exercise code above in `frac.Rnw` and then use

```
exams2moodle("frac.Rnw", converter = "ttm")
```

the resulting Moodle import looks like this in Firefox:

[image: frac MathML]

Comment: I'd prefer MathML but Chrome doesn't support it (as you wrote). The `table` isn't solution because I want a little bit complicated equations (can't workaround with html). I think I'll use: `\frac{a}{2} ... What is the value of "a"? ##ANSWER1##`. Thanks for answer.

Comment: About since a year Chrome support MathML. Why do you prefer `converter=ttm`? The spacing in math mode (`\,`, `\;`, etc.) is ugly in ttm but in pandoc-mathml is okay. But the pandoc-mathml doesn't work because in generated XML the ##ANSWERxx## are duplicated.

Comment: The details with the spacing etc may differ indeed. I typically try to avoid inserting such manually coded spaces. Also the solution from your first comment is usually more robust, i.e. using placeholders like a, b, c, etc.

Comment: Manually coded spaces: the big numbers readable with `decimal.mark="\\,"`. Maybe I'll try other `decimal.mark`.

Comment: `big.mark` not `decimal.mark` :)